# Autograd typeerror when finding gradient of scipy.stat.norm.pdf(x)

Tags: python, scipy, typeerror, normal-distribution, autograd

I want to find a simple gradient of the normal distribution pdf with scipy.stats.norm using autograd in Python.

```
import scipy.stats as stat
import autograd.numpy as np
from autograd import grad

def f(x):
    return stat.norm.pdf(x, 0.0, 1.0)

grad_f = grad(f)

print(grad_f(-1.0))
```

However, I get this typerror:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Lars/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/autograd/core.py", line 62, in forward_pass
    try: end_node = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "error.py", line 7, in f
    return stat.norm.pdf(x, 0.0, 1.0)
  File "/Users/Lars/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py", line 1657, in pdf
    putmask(output, (1-cond0)+np.isnan(x), self.badvalue)
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported typesaccording to the casting rule ''safe''

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "error.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(grad_f(-1.0))
  File "/Users/Lars/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/autograd/core.py", line 21, in gradfun
    return backward_pass(*forward_pass(fun,args,kwargs,argnum))
  File "/Users/Lars/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/autograd/core.py", line 63, in forward_pass
    except Exception as e: add_extra_error_message(e)
  File "/Users/Lars/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/autograd/core.py", line 392, in add_extra_error_message
    raise_(etype, value, traceback)
  File "/Users/Lars/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/future/utils/__init__.py", line 413, in raise_
    raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/Lars/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/autograd/core.py", line 62, in forward_pass
    try: end_node = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "error.py", line 7, in f
    return stat.norm.pdf(x, 0.0, 1.0)
  File "/Users/Lars/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py", line 1657, in pdf
    putmask(output, (1-cond0)+np.isnan(x), self.badvalue)
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported typesaccording to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Sorry for the overload of code. I have no idea what could possibly wrong with this. As far as I know, autograd supports the gradients of scipy.stats.norm.pdf()/ cdf() / logpdf() / logcdf(), as indicated by the code
https://github.com/HIPS/autograd/blob/master/autograd/scipy/stats/norm.py

Answer (score 1):

You need to import scipy from autograd, since it will appropriately wrap scipy's functions. The following works:

```py
import autograd.scipy.stats as stat     # note this import
import autograd.numpy as np
from autograd import grad

def f(x):
    return stat.norm.pdf(x, 0.0, 1.0)

grad_f = grad(f)

print(grad_f(-1.0))
```